# Jquery Return issue

Tags: jquery

How do I merge these two together?

Looking to have it so that if an email isn't entered a valid / invalid message pops up.

```js
  function showError(el, err) {
    return err ?
      $('#validate_message').html("Error: please enter a valid email address.") :
      $('#validate_message').html("Valid: press the enter key to subscribe.");
  }


  function showError(el, err) {
    return err ?
      $("#commandinput").attr("disabled", true) :
      $("#commandinput").attr("disabled", false);
  }
```

Comment: Instead of the ternary, just use and if/else

Comment: Why are you returning anything from that method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There appears to be no use of `el` in your function, this is a little confusing. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
function showError(el, err) {

    $("#commandinput").attr("disabled", false);
    $('#validate_message').html("Valid: press the enter key to subscribe.");
    if (err){
      $("#commandinput").attr("disabled", true) 
      $('#validate_message').html("Error: please enter a valid email address.");
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="validate_message"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="showError('something', false)">Validate some email address</button>
<input type="text" id="commandinput" placeholder="Enter key..." disabled></input>
```